# xamarin forms dynamically adding custom font labels to scrollview is extremely slow

Tags: performance, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a horizontal scrollview that I'm trying to dynamically populate when the user takes a certain action. The items I am throwing into the view each contain 4 labels that are using custom fonts. When I try to add about 10 of these items it lags for about 1.5 seconds on android and 1 second on IOS. If I take the custom font out then its about 1 second on each platform. If I take out 3 of the labels and only display one then its almost instantaneous. Is there any known reason for the lag? And is there any way around it so I can still use a custom font without a huge lag?

Here's a quick sample I made that pretty much does what I'm doing in my app. However, my app has more stuff so the lag isn't quite as bad here but it is still very noticeable

```
public class App : Application
{
    public int count;
    public ScrollView scroll, scroll2, scroll3;
    public App ()
    {
        count = 1;
        scroll = new ScrollView {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        scroll2 = new ScrollView {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        Button button = new Button(){
            Text = "click",
        };
        button.Clicked += (sender, e) => AddStuff();
        Button button2 = new Button(){
            Text = "click",
        };
        button2.Clicked += (sender, e) => AddStuff2();
        MainPage = new ContentPage {
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            Content = new StackLayout{
                Children={
                    button,
                    scroll,
                    button2,
                    scroll2
                }
            }
        };
    }
    //this one is instantaneous
    public void AddStuff()
    {
        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout () {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HeightRequest = 200,
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            stack.Children.Add (
                new StackLayout(){
                    Children = {
                        new Label (){TextColor = Color.Blue, Text = "Size: ", WidthRequest = 100 },
                    }
                }
            );
        scroll.Content = stack;
        count++;
    }
    //this one takes forever
    public void AddStuff2()
    {
        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout () {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HeightRequest = 200,
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            stack.Children.Add (
                new StackLayout(){
                    Children = {
                        new Label (){TextColor = Color.Blue, Text = "Size: ", WidthRequest = 100 },
                        new Label (){TextColor = Color.Blue, Text ="" + count*i, WidthRequest = 100 },
                        new Label (){TextColor = Color.Blue, Text = "Size: ", WidthRequest = 100 },
                        new Label (){TextColor = Color.Blue, Text ="" + count*i, WidthRequest = 100 }
                    }
                }
            );
        scroll2.Content = stack;
        count++;
    }
}
```

and the custom font label for droid

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Label), typeof (CustomFontLabel_Droid))]
    namespace df.Droid
    {
        public class CustomFontLabel_Droid:LabelRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Label> e) {
                base.OnElementChanged (e);
                var label = (TextView)Control;
                Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Forms.Context.Assets, "SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf");
                label.Typeface = font;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/mikescandy/Calligraphy-xamarin

I've used this to use custom fonts and works great

Comment: You claim it's slow for 10 elements but you're adding 55 to a new stack, then that stack to a scrollview. StackLayout's implementation in XF is pretty slow, a few months back I submitted a bug (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25621) because I had issues with StackLayout as well and they marked it as resolved but it was just an improvement. The root cause is the rendering engine not caching element sizes, so when the entire ScrollView needs to refresh it recalculates too many of its descendants' sizes. Whenever possible use ListView and refrain from sizable dynamic StackLayouts

Comment: Sorry, when I said 10 items I meant to items each consisting of multiple elements. And thanks for your information about stacklayouts and xamarin. Very informative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just incase anyone else is having a similar problem, if you make a static typeface property in the android MainActivity instead of calling createFromAsset inside the Label.OnElementChanged function every time then it gets rid of the extra lag on android.

CustomFontLabel_Droid.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Label), typeof (CustomFontLabel_Droid))]
namespace df.Droid
{
    public class CustomFontLabel_Droid:LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Label> e) {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            var label = (TextView)Control;
            // this guy slows things down-> Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Forms.Context.Assets, "SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf");
            label.Typeface = MainActivity.semiBoldFont;
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        public static Typeface semiBoldFont = null;
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
            LoadApplication (new App ());
            semiBoldFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Forms.Context.Assets, "SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf");
        }
    }
```